# Instantiate Android SipManager in c++ builder

Tags: android, c++, sip, c++builder

I'm trying to instantiate the SipManager (developer.android.com) in Embarcadero with c++ builder but I'm not able to find the right way.
For this, I'm using Delphi Interface instances.

In Java it is like this:

```
public static SipManager manager;
manager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
//Context is the application context for creating the manager object.
```

For the correct compilation of the code that will appear next, it is necessary to include the following:

```
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
    #include <Androidapi.Helpers.HPP>
    #include <Androidapi.JNI.Net.HPP>
    #include <Androidapi.JNI.os.HPP>
    #include <Androidapi.JNI.Support.HPP>
    #include <Androidapi.JNI.Media.HPP>
#endif
```

In addition, the "Use Sip" and "Internet" permissions must also be added to the manifest.

I tried to do it in many ways, based on the fact that I already knew how to install the WifiManager:

```
#if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
    _di_JObject obj;
    _diJWifiManager wm;
    obj = SharedActivityContext()->getSystemService(TJContext::JavaClass->WIFI_SERVICE);
    wm = TJWifiManager::Wrap(((_di_ILocalObject)obj)->GetObjectID());
    wm->setWifiEnabled(true);
#endif
```

For my application I have done the following:

1. This compiles but when running the application it says that the method init() is not found.

   ```
   #if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
       _di_JObject obj;
       _di_JSipManager sipm;
       obj = TJSipManager::JavaClass->init();
       sipm = TJSipManager::Wrap(((_di_ILocalObject)obj)->GetObjectID());
   #endif
   ```
2. This compiles too, but when running the application, this one has an exception kind of "Abort".

   ```
   #if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
       _di_JSipManager sipm;
       sipm = TJSipManager::Create();
   #endif
   ```
3. This compiles too, but when running the application, this one has an exception kind of "Access Violation".

   ```
   #if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
       _di_JSipManager sipm;
       sipm = TJSipManager::JavaClass;
   #endif
   ```
4. This compiles too, but it has an exception kind of "Abort" when I try to open the profile.

   ```
   #if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
       _di_JSipManager sipm;
       _di_JContext context;
       _di_JSipProfileBuilder sippb;
       _di_JSipProfile sipp;
       context = SharedActivityContext()->getApplicationContext();
       TJSipManager *sipn = new TJSipManager();
       sipm = sipn->Wrap(((_di_ILocalObject)context) >GetObjectID());
       _di_JString uri;
       uri = StringToJString("sip:165@40.134.279.145:5060");
       sippb = TJSipProfile_Builder::JavaClass->init(uri);
       sipp = sippb->build();
       sipm->open(sipp);
   #endif
   ```

If I do only the part of the SipProfile, there is no problem and the profile is built.

```
#if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
    _di_JSipProfileBuilder sippb;
    _di_JSipProfile sipp;
    _di_JString uri;
    uri = StringToJString("sip:165@40.134.279.145:5060");
    sippb = TJSipProfile_Builder::JavaClass->init(uri);
    sipp = sippb->build();
#endif
```

And in Java it is like this:

```
public static SipProfile me;
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("uri");
me = builder.build();
```

I would like to know how to instantiate the SipManager for c++ builder.
In Java, it has been seen that it uses the method "newInstance(context)" for it, 
but when I try to instantiate it in C++ builder it doesn't appear any similar method that belongs to this class.

1. Can I instantiate in C++ builder?
2. What's the right way to do it?
3. If not possible, is there another library to make a Sip application in Embarcadero with c++ builder?

---

In another forum, Remy replied:

"It SHOULD be something as simple as this in C++Builder:

```
#if defined (_PLAT_ANDROID)
    _di_JSipManager manager = TJSipManager::JavaClass->newInstance(SharedActivityContext());
    // use manager as needed...
#endif
```

But in actuality, this doesn't work (at least in Seattle, don't know about later versions) because the static newInstance() method is MISSING from the JSipManagerClass interface in Androidapi.JNI.Net.hpp!

You could try using Java2OP to re-import the SipManager class, but I don't know if that will end up suffering from the same problem or not."

---

But I have the last release of Tokio and I still have the same problem.
I will try to re-import the SipManager.

Comment: Minor point: do you realise there is a pre-defined compiler symbol for the Android platform: `__ANDROID__` - maybe there is some mileage in using that rather then (and I'm guessing on this point) crafting a custom one: `_PLAT_ANDROID` ?

Comment: It is a predefined symbol for the compilation mode in Android

Comment: LRA, thanks for the clarification. Odd that it doesn't appear in the list of predefined symbols at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Predefined_Macros - I wonder what declares it: compiler of some Android platform header.... I may have to go seek it out unless you happen to know.

Comment: typo: "compiler *or* some Android platform header"

Comment: I don't know what header calls it, I have based myself on previously implemented code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your offerings and see why they don't work:

1) you are calling the parameterless Java constructor, surfaced as `init()` but this class is not meant to be constructed through a regular constructor. One presumes that constructor is private, but regardless, the documentation says you create an instance through `newInstance()`.

2) invoking the import class `Create()` class method is normally much the same as calling `init()`, but done through a different avenue. Given `init` is not available it fails, just with a different symptom here.

3) You have declared a variable of the Delphi `JSipManager` instance methods interface type, but then assigned it the `JavaClass` property, which gives the Delphi `JSipManagerClass` class methods interface type. Those 2 are not the same. An error is to be expected.

4) The template class `TJSipManager` is a helper to gain access to the class methods interface (through the `JavaClass` property) or to instance methods via an instance created by invoking a constructor (maybe via `Create()` or `JavaClass->init()`. You shouldn't construct an instance of this template class - it serves no valid purpose.
Proceeding to cast (via `Wrap()`) the context object into a `SipManager` smacks of desperation - they are wholly disparate types.

OK, now let's see why what should work doesn't work.

The reason the `newInstance()` method (and others) are commented out of the `JSipManagerClass` class methods interface in the original Delphi unit, Androidapi.JNI.Net.pas, is that they all have a parameter or a return type such as `JContext` or `JIntent` that is defined and exposed from a unit that already uses Androidapi.JNI.Net.pas, namely the unit Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.pas.

Java2OP has left the methods there because they exist, but commented them out to avoid a circular unit reference error.

What will work is to redefine the `SipManager` JNI Bridge types in a new Delphi unit, add that new unit to your C++ project, include its generated header and proceed from there.

To make the unit you can right-click on the project in the Project Manager and choose Add New, Unit - Delphi. If you are using C++ Builder only (with no Delphi support) just create the unit in a text editor. It's called Androidapi.JNI.SIP.pas and contains the import of just one type: `SipManager` - to avoid fighting with ambiguity I've called the base import interface `JSipManager2`:

```
unit Androidapi.JNI.SIP;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os;

type
// ===== Forward declarations =====

  JSipManager2 = interface;//android.net.sip.SipManager

  JSipManager2Class = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{62C12348-C7E4-4B5E-AE75-715EAAFD4465}']
    {class} function _GetEXTRA_CALL_ID: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetEXTRA_OFFER_SD: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetINCOMING_CALL_RESULT_CODE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function getCallId(incomingCallIntent: JIntent): JString; cdecl;
    {class} function getOfferSessionDescription(incomingCallIntent: JIntent): JString; cdecl;
    {class} function isApiSupported(context: JContext): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isIncomingCallIntent(intent: JIntent): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isSipWifiOnly(context: JContext): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isVoipSupported(context: JContext): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function newInstance(context: JContext): JSipManager2; cdecl;
    {class} property EXTRA_CALL_ID: JString read _GetEXTRA_CALL_ID;
    {class} property EXTRA_OFFER_SD: JString read _GetEXTRA_OFFER_SD;
    {class} property INCOMING_CALL_RESULT_CODE: Integer read _GetINCOMING_CALL_RESULT_CODE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/net/sip/SipManager')]
  JSipManager2 = interface(JObject)
    ['{EDE899E1-4774-41FB-BC53-03BB69565231}']
    procedure close(localProfileUri: JString); cdecl;
    function createSipSession(localProfile: JSipProfile; listener: JSipSession_Listener): JSipSession; cdecl;
    //function getSessionFor(incomingCallIntent: JIntent): JSipSession; cdecl;
    function isOpened(localProfileUri: JString): Boolean; cdecl;
    function isRegistered(localProfileUri: JString): Boolean; cdecl;
    function makeAudioCall(localProfile: JSipProfile; peerProfile: JSipProfile; listener: JSipAudioCall_Listener; timeout: Integer): JSipAudioCall; cdecl; overload;
    function makeAudioCall(localProfileUri: JString; peerProfileUri: JString; listener: JSipAudioCall_Listener; timeout: Integer): JSipAudioCall; cdecl; overload;
    procedure open(localProfile: JSipProfile); cdecl; overload;
    //procedure open(localProfile: JSipProfile; incomingCallPendingIntent: JPendingIntent; listener: JSipRegistrationListener); cdecl; overload;
    procedure register(localProfile: JSipProfile; expiryTime: Integer; listener: JSipRegistrationListener); cdecl;
    procedure setRegistrationListener(localProfileUri: JString; listener: JSipRegistrationListener); cdecl;
    //function takeAudioCall(incomingCallIntent: JIntent; listener: JSipAudioCall_Listener): JSipAudioCall; cdecl;
    procedure unregister(localProfile: JSipProfile; listener: JSipRegistrationListener); cdecl;
  end;
  TJSipManager2 = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSipManager2Class, JSipManager2>) end;

implementation

procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('Androidapi.JNI.SIP.JSipManager2', TypeInfo(Androidapi.JNI.SIP.JSipManager2));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTypes;
end.
```

Then use it in some C++ code like this:

```
...
// Cleanse build of lots of errors about __cdecl...
#define __cdecl
#include "Androidapi.JNI.SIP.hpp"
#include <Androidapi.Helpers.hpp>
...
    _di_JSipManager2 manager = TJSipManager2::JavaClass->newInstance(TAndroidHelper::Context);
    // use manager as needed...
```

This seems to compile and execute OK, but I have no SIP service so cannot get further than that.

As a parting comment, the global `SharedActivityContext()` function is deprecated - the `TAndroidHelper` class now contains all that sort of thing as static methods/properties such as `TAndroidHelper::Context`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I have tested it and it also works for me, I will continue with the implementation of SIP.